# In Oracle SQL, how do you query the proportion of records of a certain value?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Say, you have a query like

```
SELECT COUNT(*), date FROM ORDERS GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

but you also want to have a third "phantom/dummy field", where it basically tells you the fraction of orders each day that are of a particular type (lets say "Utensils" and "Perishables").

I should say that there is an additional column in the ORDERS table that has the type of the order:

```
order_type
```

The third dummy column should do something like take the count of orders on a date that have the "Utensils" or the "Perishables" type (not XOR), then divide by the total count of orders of that day, and then round to 2 decimal points, and append a percentage sign.

The last few formatting things, aren't really important...all I really need to know is how to apply the logic in valid PLSQL syntax.

Example output

```
4030 2012-02-02 34.43%
4953 2012-02-03 16.66%
```

Comment: Can you show an example of output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       dt,
       round( SUM( CASE WHEN order_type = 'Utensils'
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END) * 100 / COUNT(*),2) fraction_of_utensils_orders
  FROM ORDERS 
 GROUP BY dt
 ORDER BY st
```

If you find it easier to follow, you could also

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       dt,
       round( COUNT( CASE WHEN order_type = 'Utensils'
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE NULL
                      END) * 100/ COUNT(*), 2) fraction_of_utensils_orders
  FROM ORDERS 
 GROUP BY dt
 ORDER BY st
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken in PL/SQL you will have to use DECODE instead of CASE.

Comment: @DannyVarod - `CASE` is valid in PL/SQL (though the syntax is a bit different than the syntax in SQL).  But we're not actually talking about PL/SQL at the moment-- this appears to be strictly a SQL question.

Comment: Question title and tags say PLSQL.

Comment: Is SQL considered the open language that is shared by PLSQL, TSQL and DB2?

Comment: @JustinCave Isn't PL/SQL always Oracle SQL? - In that case weren't the title and tags OK?

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn I think you mean "ANSI SQL" and that SQL can be any sub-type of SQL.

Comment: @DannyVarod - PL/SQL is a procedural extension to SQL that is specific to Oracle.  PL/SQL is a separate virtual machine inside the database from the SQL virtual machine.  Oracle, like other databases, also has its own dialect of SQL which is based on the ANSI standard but that has its own proprietary extensions.

Comment: Oh so ANSI SQL works with all vendors (but I assume is limited in scope/functionality)
I know this is offtopic but I don't feel like creating a seperate topic for it: What is the SQL Server Managmenet Studio/querying tool equivalent for Oracle databases?

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - Depends.  Some combination of Enterprise Manager, SQL Developer, and SQL*Plus most likely.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn This belongs in a separate question, however, there are many. Oracle's free tool is called "Oracle SQL Developer".

Answer (score 1):

To Add sum of orders of same type to query:

```
select
    o.*,
    (
        select count(o2.OrderType)
        from ORDERS o2
        where o2.OrderType = o.OrderType
    ) as NumberOfOrdersOfThisType
from ORDERS o
```

To Add fraction of orders of same type to query:
(Check variable definition to make sure it is PL/SQL)

```
declare totalCount number

select count(*)
into totalCount
from ORDERS

select
    o.*,
    (
        select count(o2.OrderType)
        from ORDERS o2
        where o2.OrderType = o.OrderType
    ) / totalCount as FractionOfOrdersOfThisType
from ORDERS o
```